# SELECT query for multiple checkbox in HTML (PHP, Postgresql)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, select, checkbox

I need to make **dynamic SQL** query that returns several columns from DB, depending on what data was checked in checkbox html form. In this code it only returns **last column of data** that was checked, **not all**. I can only think of examining all combination with IF clause, but since in practice I have much more checkboxes then 3, I'm wondering if someone can suggest some dynamic solution.

```
<?php
// Connecting to a Postgresql DB
...
// Values sent from HTML form
$checked = $_POST["check_list"];
$submit = $_POST["submit"];
?>

<form action="" method="POST">  
Choose:
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="5"> 5h    
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="6"> 6h    
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="7"> 7h    
<br><br>    
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

 <?php
// Checking if something is checked
// If it is do something
if(isset($submit)){
    if(empty($checked)){
        echo "Please choose something";     
    } else {        
        foreach($checked as $selected){
            // Adding 0 in front of one dimensional numbers because of DB column name
            if ($selected < 10){
                $selected = "0$selected";
            }
            $db_colum_name = "a_b$selected";

            $query = "SELECT table1. name,
                             table1. latitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lat,
                             table1. longitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lng,
                             EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) AS year,
                             table2. $db_colum_name AS $selected
                     FROM table1
                     JOIN table2 
                     ON table1.id=table2.id
                     WHERE
                     name = 'New York'
                     AND
                     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) = '2000'
                     ORDER BY date DESC";

            $result = pg_query($dbcon, $query) or die("Your error: {$query} <br>");
        }

        // Printing data
        ...
        // Closing DB connection
        pg_close ($dbcon);

    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:

Somekind of schema:

*table 1*

id | name    | latitude | longitude |
5  | New York|   40.7   | -74.00    |

*table 2*

id | date      | a_b05 | a_b06 | a_b07 |
5  |2000-03-02 |  100  |  105  |  200  |

Comment: Share your SQL database schema for the tables that are involved here? I can tell you offhand your problem is each foreach overwrites your result variable. You should design the SQL statement so that each foreach adds to it and then perform the query after the iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is have a string that appends a string for every iteration of the loop that would be added to the query string.

```
$stringBuilder .= ", table2.$db_colum_name as $selected";
```

Another thing is to move the query outside of the loop so that it only fetches the results once and not for every iteration. Then you could append the `$stringBuilder` to the query

```
 $query = "SELECT table1. name,
        table1. latitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lat,
        table1. longitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lng,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) AS year
        $stringBuilder
```

So after all that it would look something like this:

```
$stringBuilder = "";
foreach($checked as $selected){
    // Adding 0 in front of one dimensional numbers because of DB column name
    if ($selected < 10){
        $selected = "0$selected";
    }
    $db_colum_name = "a_b$selected";
    $stringBuilder .= ", table2.$db_colum_name as $selected";
}

$query = "SELECT table1. name,
        table1. latitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lat,
        table1. longitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lng,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) AS year
        $stringBuilder
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id=table2.id
    WHERE
    name = 'New York'
    AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) = '2000'
    ORDER BY date DESC";

$result = pg_query($dbcon, $query) or die("Error: {$query} <br>");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This stuff is working! Very nice solution! Thank you! At first I left comma before $stringBuilder in query so I had some problems, but this is working lika a charm now!

Comment: No problem, glad it helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The schemea you're using is less than optimal. Look into database normalization, it both helps in future proofing your data as well as making it easier to write powerful SQL queries.

If the desired output is something like this:

```
name      lat                lng   a_b05_year  a_b05  a_b06_year  a_b06  a_b07_year  a_b07  
New York  4.070000076293946  -7.4  2000        100    2000        105    2000        200
```

Then this query should do the trick with your current schema:

```
$array = array('5', '6', '7'); //Simulated checkbox return. In '' because they're strings not integers

$select = "SELECT table1.name, table1.latitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lat, table1.longitude / CAST(10 AS FLOAT(6)) AS lng,";
$q = "";

$count = count($array); //how many checkboxes returned
$i = 1;

foreach($array as $val)
{
    if(strlen($val) < 2)
        $val = '0'.$val;

    $col    = "a_b".$val;
    $alias  = "a_b".$val; //Because you're getting multiple of the same column (date) from the same table, this needs to be handled via joins with aliases.
    $select .= " EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ". $alias .".date) AS ". $alias ."_year, "; //This seems redundent, if you know the year why select it?
    $select .= $alias .".".$col." AS ".$alias;
    if($i < $count)
        $select .=",";

    $q      .= " JOIN (SELECT table2.id, table2.".$col.", table2.date FROM table2 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2.date) = '2000') AS ".$alias ." ON ".$alias.".id=table1.id";

    $i++;
}
$select .=" FROM table1";
$q = $select . $q;
```

The problem though, is if your also going to change the location "New York" or the year. So far you're associating the date and a_b values on an ID match to the New York location. What if for a_b06 they want Los Angeles in 2002?

I would strongly advise a table structure as follows:

```
locations
id      name        lng         lat
auto    NYC         X           Y
auto    LA          X           Y
auto    MIAMI       X           Y

values 
id      loc_id           date            key     value
auto    1 (NYC's auto)   2002-10-25      6       100
auto    1 (NYC's auto)   2001-10-25      5      150
auto    1 (NYC's auto)   2000-10-25      7      207
```

Then say your user chooses keys 5, 6, 7 and NYC, then the following PHP to build the query:

```
$array = array('5', '6', '7'); //Simulated checkbox return. In '' because they're strings not integers
$loc = "NYC";

$q =    'SELECT     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `values`.date) as year,
                    `values`.key,
                    `values`.value,
                    locations.lat / CAST( 10 as FLOAT(6) ) as lat,
                    locations.lng / CAST( 10 as FLOAT(6) ) as lng
         FROM `values`
                JOIN locations ON locations.id = values.loc_id
         WHERE `values`.loc_id IN (SELECT locations.id FROM locations where locations.name = "'.$loc.'")
         AND values.key IN (';

$countVal = count($array);
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $q .= $value;
    if($i < $countVal)
        $q .= ",";

    $i++;
}

$q .= ") 
ORDER BY `values`.date DESC";
```

Which will return:

```
year  key  value  lat                lng   
2002  6    100    4.070000076293946  -7.4  
2001  5    150    4.070000076293946  -7.4  
2000  7    207    4.070000076293946  -7.4
```

Which I think is closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thnx for prompt reply! I wrote some sort of schema, hopefully it will have some sort of meaning to you.

Comment: Business logic wise, what is going on in table_2. Offhand, I can tell you are going to run into problems with your data if you have a column for every possible checkbox. If I know the business logic, I can advise an adjustment in your SQL structure that will help you retrieve what you're after in a more normalized fashion. Short of that, I'll take a look in a bit and see what I can do.
@vayacondios2015

Comment: Thank you! I will be waiting for your reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation! In **EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ". $alias .".date) AS ". $alias ."_year, ";** I wasn't extracting the year, it was supposed to stay the way it is: **EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table2. date) AS year**, it was just a simple try to see if checkbox is working, and the year I would choose through simple box input later on when I expend my form. Later I will take a look at your reply more detailed, since I'm not able to connect to the DB right now. I can see there are some tricks which would be useful to know for the future coding. I tried answer @Jujunol gave, it seems to

Comment: be less complicated, although it is in some sort of way very similar as I can see as beginner in programming. **What do you think of it?** And I only know little about optimization (normalization) of DB, but thanks for pointing that out although I don't have privileges to change settings of it.

Comment: Database normalization is the theories behind relational database design. I like [this](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) tutorial, but google has many [others](https://www.google.com/?q=Database+normalization+tutorial).

I think Jujunol's solution makes better use of what you already have. I missinterpreted your need for unique years for each column returned. Never the less, its a good rule if your'e using column names dynamically you're doing something wrong in your database design. @vayacondios2015